# How to block All IPs in IIS7 with Address and Domain Restrictions

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, iis-7

I want to block everyone from accessing my website but me. I am using IIS7 and have IPv4 Address and domain Restrictions installed.

Comment: How will you authenticate yourself as "me"? This is necessary to block "the others".

Answer (score 0):

You can block by IP, you can block by domain, you can require authentication, this is all up to you.  But you have to decide which path to take.